# Powershell WebRequest Double Header Use

Tags: powershell

- 'X-Forwarded-Host' =  'mywebsite.com'
- 

Duplicate keys 'X-Forwarded-Host' are not allowed in hash literals.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DuplicateKeyInHashLiteral

I need to use a header twice. how can I do it?

```
$headers = @{
'content-type' =  'application/json'
'X-Forwarded-Host' =  'mywebsite.com'
'X-Forwarded-Host' =  'mywebsite.com'
'authorization' = "token"
}
```

Invoke-WebRequest - .ps1

Comment: I don't know if it works, but try using an _array_: `'X-Forwarded-Host' =  'mywebsite1.com', 'mywebsite2.com'`

Comment: Can you explain why you need to have a duplicate header?